# Set redirect status code to 503 in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When redirect user to Page(view) B from Page(view) A. I can see in browser developer tool status code for Page A is 302 since its redirect. I want to change status code to 503 for Page A. How can i achieve this? any inputs or suggestion.

I tried below code but it did not work. Still getting 302 status code for page A.

```
  Response.StatusCode = (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
  Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
  Response.Redirect("https://localhost:44300/b",false);
  Response.End();
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect` can only return a 30x code. If you want to return 503, or any other code, use `HttpStatusCodeResult` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2 BTW, 503 should only be returned by IIS when application pools fail, so you should return 500 from your own web app.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw exception instead

`throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);`

And configure page B as error page for status code 503.

`<error statusCode="503" redirect="page_B.aspx"/>`